# for loop does not yield a concrete answer when applied between a string and lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a string of adjectives obtained using pos_tag and word_tokenize from nltk. There are 7 lists as:

```
positiverange4 = ['legendary', 'legend', 'finest', 'insane', 'best']    
positiverange3 = ['favorite', 'favourite', 'fav', 'delicious', 'awesome', 'perfect', 'perfection', 'perfectly', 'scrumptous']    
positiverange2 = ['love', 'courteous', 'great', 'generous', 'tasty', 'pleasent', 'polite']    
positiverange1 = ['like', 'enjoyable', 'enjoy', 'reasonable', 'huge', 'plentiful', 'plenty', 'quick', 'enjoyed', 'fast', 'swift']
neutralrange   = ['ok', 'fine', 'good', 'nice', 'gud', 'friendly', 'fresh', 'cheap']
negativerange1 = ['crowded', 'lousy', 'slow', 'bad']
```

i start a for loop that checks if a word in that string is in any of these lists and if it exits I increment the counter like this

```
count = 0
for w in adjectives:
    if w in positiverange4:
        val += 4 
        count = count + 1
    elif w in positiverange3:
        val += 3
        count = count + 1
    elif w in positiverange2:
        val += 2
        count = count + 1
    elif w in positiverange1:
        val += 1
        count = count + 1
    elif w in neutralrange:
        val += 0
        count = count + 1
    elif w in negativerange1:
        val -= 1
        count = count + 1
    elif w in negativerange2:
        val -= 2
        count = count + 1
    elif w in negativerange3:
        val -= 3
        count = count + 1   
    elif w in negativerange4:
        val -= 4
        count = count + 1                               
print count
```

the value of count comes wrong many times.

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? It counts the number of words in `adjectives` that are in one of your lists. Can you give input and expected output?

Comment: What exactly is `adjectives`?

Comment: Try `for w.strip().lower() in adjectives:`

Comment: adjective is a string of adjectives obtained using pos_tag and word_tokenize .its somewhat like this..['general', 'nice', 'easy', 'good', 'great', 'scrumptious', 'affiliated', 'top-notch', 'important', 'more']
['many', 'other', 'good', 'terrible', 'bad', 'many', 'other', 'medical', 'incomprehensible', 'regret']
['efficient', 'great', 'enjoyable', 'friendly', 'few', 'authoritative', 'glad']

Comment: Is `adjectives` a nested list.

Comment: Should you be printing `value` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I am with BATH IRSHAD, *normalize* your input.  And also your reference data (see below). Further, a `dict`ionary of `set`s <del>could be</del> definitely is a better data structure for your use case

```
known_adj = {+4: {'legendary', 'legend', 'finest', 'insane', 'best'},
             +3: {'favorite', 'favourite', 'fav', 'delicious', 'awesome',
                  'perfect', 'perfection', 'perfectly', 'scrumptous'},
             ... }

total_val = sum(val for val in known_adj for adj in adjectives
                             if adj.strip().lower() in known_adj[val])
```

a `for` loop can be more efficient if you skip further comparisons after a match (**Edit:** *and provides also an easy way to compute the total number of matches that the OP's program accumulates during its loop,* this detail just slipped my mind...)

```
total_val = 0
# added in edit
total_matches = 0
for adj in adjectives:
    adj = adj.strip().lower()
    for val in known_adj:
        if adj in known_adj[val]:
             total_val += val
             # added in edit
             total_matches += 1
             continue
```

Another thing that you may want to do is *sanitize* `known_adj`

```
 from itertools import combinations
 ...
 known_adj = update_ka()
 for i, j in combinations(known_adj.keys(),2):
     if known_adj[i].intersection(known_adj[j]):
         # not an empty set, there is a repetition!
         # print/log a warning, stop the machines, etc, you decide
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using `collections` module

---

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> # Tally occurrences of words in a list
>>> cnt = Counter()
>>> for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
...     cnt[word] += 1
>>> cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

**Bibliography:**
8.3. collections — High-performance container datatypes — http://goo.gl/GGWYrW
9.7. itertools — Functions creating iterators for efficient looping — http://goo.gl/GKfVXQ
Python Lists http://goo.gl/HZ9Hm
Online Demo http://repl.it/4NP
Execute Python Script Online http://goo.gl/4sxrD

Comment: Here the use of a `Counter` leads to a loop over data, to _fill_ the `Counter`, and later to a loop on `Counter` to compute the scores. OTOH if the OP's program has other uses for the counts of unique adjectives...